# Templating within a plugin - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**I need to create a plugin used to create a part of a web page.**

Therefore, it would be very useful for me to **create a php template** to be used by the plugin to generate the content.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything within the Plugin API and I'm quite confused about it right now.

---

The plugin needs to generate a list of images. Simple HTML with a for loop.

I would like to avoid this:

```
function insert_gallery(){

    $images = $SQL_QUERY();
    for(...){
        echo 'string'+$variable+'string'+$method()+'string'+$variable;
    }

}

add_action('insert_gallery', 'insert_gallery')
```

---

**Help would be amazing. :)**

Comment: You have to clarify this. What is the plugin suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:
http://www.stiengenterprises.com/download/wp-filebrowser/wp-filebrowser_0.3.zip

This is a plugin that I have just created for selecting a image to attach / relate to a post / page. Look at the code and you can see how I generate the image listing.

It's not finished, just an early version.

Will only work on WP 3.0 or later.

Hope this helps :)